# Django - Loading a page that has external authentication changes the session_key

Tags: django, session, authentication

I'm trying to migrate a project from Django 1.4 to Django 1.5.1 ...

The web service has to be accessible both as authenticated and anonymous user. And we use external authentication with an Apache module (which sets "REMOTE_USER" env var in accordance with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/auth-remote-user/).

The url https://example.com/ has a different content depending if the user is anonymous or authenticated.

The strategy we used with Django 1.4 was that only the urls starting by /auth/ are authenticated by Apache's module. If the user (being on page https://example.com/) chooses to authenticate, he jumps to https://example.com/auth/ . The /auth/ is authenticated by Apache's module, then served by Django application which redirects back to https://example.com/ . Because of the session_key, Django knows that the user is authenticated.

Unfortunately with Django 1.5.1 ... the session_key is changed every time the browser moves from an authenticated url to an non-authenticated one.

In my log, I can see (Django 1.5.1) :

```
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:15:20,571 views home None
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:15:48,886 views auth ow1bzgdajs7i12d9bmfwwm3fpw47elna
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:15:48,981 views home mehlf1x0iemx9yc3ddf6mhnls1nha1r4
```

- First line is when the user access https://example.com/ .
- Second when he clicks on button "Connexion" .
- Third is an HttpResponseRedirect to / .
- The last string is the request.session.session_key .

When I remove the apache authentication on /auth (Django 1.5.1) :

```
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:16:45,268 views home None
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:16:48,258 views auth None
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:16:48,345 views home None
```

With Django 1.4, here is what the same log gives :

```
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:11:21,899 views home None
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:11:41,261 views auth f16ab3e574b866177803f9011dc33ab8
DEBUG 2013-04-09 09:11:41,375 views home f16ab3e574b866177803f9011dc33ab8
```

Is this change of behavior expected? (new feature?)
How could we fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by Aymeric, this is an intended bugfix that appeared in Django 1.5. :) :(

In our case, we really need the session to persist even when Apache's modules don't provide anymore the "REMOTE_USER" variable.
To solve this, I've found 2 possibilities :

1. subclass RemoteUserMiddleware and redefine only the method process_request without the piece of code auth.logout(request)
2. Insert a homemade middleware that inject the username into REMOTE_USER when needed.

I choosed the second possibility because it will/should be zero-effort to adapt to upcoming versions of Django.

In my settings.py I added `'main.middleware.persistant_session_middleware'` just before `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware'`

and defined **persistant_session_middleware** in main/middleware.py :

```
class persistant_session_middleware(object):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def process_request(self, request):
    header = "REMOTE_USER"

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and not header in request.META:
        request.META[header] = request.user.username
    return None
```

I just hope this won't be a security hole! But as long as it depends on `request.user.is_authenticated()` I think we are safe :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bugfix: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17869.

It's documented in the release notes for Django 1.5 :

> RemoteUserMiddleware now forces logout when the REMOTE_USER header disappears during the same browser session.

Comment: Something strange is still going on. I have the same problem even when REMOTE_USER is provided on every page, the session_key still changes on every pageview which nukes anything that was stored in the session.

Comment: Well, solved my problem. I had two version of RemoteUserMiddleware, a custom one for a different header that would be populated by our reverseproxy. First one logged the user out, then the second one logged back in on every page view.